# Auto Data Binding occurs when Binding two same-type instances to two Spring MVC forms

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-form

In the jsp file:

```
<sf:form ... action="queryUser" modelAttribute="user_a">
    <sf:input path="name"/>
   <input type="submit" id="submit1"/>
</sf:form>

<sf:form ...action="addUser" modelAttribute="user_b">
    <sf:input path="name"/>
   <input type="submit" id="submit2"/>
</sf:form>
```

In the Java file:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
@SessionAttributes("user_a")
public class UserController
{
   ...
   RequestMapping("/addUser")
   public void function(@ModelAttribute("user_a") User user_a,@ModelAttribute("user_b") User user_b,BindingResult bindingResult)
{
  ...
}

}
```

Here is the problem: when I click the submit2.
the request entity user_b will be passed to both user_a and user_b!!

Who knows how to distinguish them??

Comment: why you have the `user_a` object in the `addUser` Method? If i look at your jsp file i can see each user object have a different action

Comment: Yes, there is another function for /queryUser. But, as you can see, user_a is a session attribute, and I use it to record the history query conditions. My core problem is that: I use spring form to post a model entity named "user_b", and  why does the spring copy it and give it to both user_a and user_b.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem.
When in the case like in the problem:

```
RequestMapping("/addUser")
public void function(@ModelAttribute("user_a") User user_a,@ModelAttribute("user_b") User user_b,BindingResult bindingResult)
{
  ...
}
```

The only possibility that you use two same-type objects in one controller's function and do not want to modify certain one at the same time is that one of them has already been filled previously, and you want to use it in this function. Or you agree to modify both of them (in this case, you would pass two different entities).
So, in the situation that I encountered, just do not list the object in the function's parameters. And you can access the ready-made model attribute by codes like:

```
RequestMapping("/addUser")
public void function(Model model,@ModelAttribute("user_b") User user_b,BindingResult bindingResult)
{
  // if this is a session attribute, it will not be changed.
  User user_a = model.get("user_a");
  //more codes go here
}
```

In conclusion, spring MVC framework will bound one valid object of the request to all the same-type variables when there is only one valid object and there are multiple same-type objects in the function's parameter list.
One sentence principle:
Binding operation of a variable take place when and only when you list it in the function's parameter list.